# read multiple files using utilities in databricks

Tags: pyspark, apache-commons-dbutils, dbutils

I have multiple files like
I tried using

```
%python

dbutils.fs.ls(
 [
   "/mnt/nikhil/2024",
   "/mnt/nikhil/2023",
   "/mnt/akhil/2023",
   "/mnt/akhil/2024"
 ]
)
```

Paths of files are

```
1)/mnt/nikhil/2024
2)/mnt/nikhil/2023
3)/mnt/akhil/2024
4)/mnt/akhil/2023
```

my requirement is to display content of all files of above path

can anyone help me please?

Comment: what is file format ? May be you can use `spark.read.<file_format>(<path>, <path>..)`

Comment: no file format, here we are using db.utils to get the files that are there in the path... when we use db.utils.fs.ls("/mnt/nikhil/2024"),it is working  for 1 reading 1 file...but while reading multiple files,i am getting error